# Xabre BLE Android respectively slow at scanning and connecting

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an application in which I use the Xabre library to connect to a BLE device.

On Android (I have tested on a Galaxy A40 and a Galaxy S7), I experience that the application utilize alot of time to respectively scan and connect.

I have changed the latency of my ScanMode to `ScanMode.LowLatency` - Which increased the scan-time a small bit. (though still unacceptable)

Additionally, when the device connects to a Device, it spends a lot of time and reconnects several times before connecting. (Yes, the device is within proximity, and other apps like LightBlue connects without any problems)

During connection I have set my ConnectParameters to `ConnectParameters(true, true);`.

I have not tested on iOS yet with this project, but have previously used Xabre for iOS where I didn't experience similar behavior.

The following code that I'm working with is:

```
public async void Connect(IDevice unit)
{
    await adapter.StopScanningForDevicesAsync();
    try
    {
        var parameters = new ConnectParameters(true, true);
        await adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(unit, parameters);
        //Add device
        Bluetooth.Device = unit;
        Console.Write(unit.Id);
        //Add service and characteristics to Device object
        Bluetooth.Service = await Bluetooth.Device.GetServiceAsync(Guid.Parse(Service_UUID));
        Bluetooth.Characteristic = await Bluetooth.Service.GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse(Characteristic_UUID));
        Characteristic_ValueUpdated();
    }
    catch (DeviceConnectionException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
        Connect(unit);
    }
}
public async void Disconnect()
{
    try
    {
        await Characteristic.StopUpdatesAsync();
        await adapter.DisconnectDeviceAsync(Device);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
public async void Scan()
{
    adapter.ScanMode = ScanMode.LowLatency;
    adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
    {
        if (a.Device.Name == "Device_name")
        {
                Connect(a.Device);
        }
    };
    await adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
}
```

On Galaxy S7 things generally run abit faster, but I still experience several reconnects.

Comment: try to set a time limit on your scan

Comment: How would that help? My BLE device has a nRF51802 chip. I suspect that may be the one troubling me.